# MSBuild nuget package: what to add to .csproj file?

Tags: c#, msbuild, nuget

I'm compiling and running a C# project through the terminal, using MSBuild, and it's working fine.

Now, I need to add some nuget packages to my project (namely, SQLite).

This is what I added to `myproj.csproj`:

```
<!-- NuGet Packages -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="EntityFramework" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SQLite" Version="1.0.108.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SQLite.Core" Version="1.0.108.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" Version="1.0.108.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SQLite.Linq" Version="1.0.108.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

However, when I run `msbuild myproj.csproj` I get the error `The type or namespace SQLite does not exist...`.

Do I need to add anything else?

Here's the full file:

```
<Project DefaultTargets = "All" 
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <!-- Server -->
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ServerAssemblyName>server.exe</ServerAssemblyName>
    <ServerSrcPath>src/server/</ServerSrcPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <!-- Client -->
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ClientAssemblyName>client.exe</ClientAssemblyName>
    <ClientSrcPath>src/client/</ClientSrcPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <!-- Common -->
  <PropertyGroup>
    <CommonAssemblyName>common.dll</CommonAssemblyName>
    <CommonSrcPath>src/common/</CommonSrcPath>
    <OutputPath>bin/</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <!-- Server -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <ServerCompile Include="$(ServerSrcPath)Server.cs" />
    <ServerCompile Include="$(ServerSrcPath)Diginote.cs" />
    <ServerCompile Include="$(ServerSrcPath)DB.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <!-- Client -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClientCompile Include="$(ClientSrcPath)Client.cs" />
    <ClientCompile Include="$(ClientSrcPath)cli/CLI.cs" />
    <ClientCompile Include="$(ClientSrcPath)cli/Menu.cs" />
    <ClientCompile Include="$(ClientSrcPath)cli/MainMenu.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <!-- Common -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <CommonCompile Include="$(CommonSrcPath)Common.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <!-- NuGet Packages -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="EntityFramework" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SQLite" Version="1.0.108.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SQLite.Core" Version="1.0.108.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" Version="1.0.108.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SQLite.Linq" Version="1.0.108.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <!-- Server -->
  <Target Name="Server" DependsOnTargets="Common" Inputs="@(ServerCompile)" Outputs="$(OutputPath)$(ServerAssemblyName)">
    <MakeDir Directories="$(OutputPath)" Condition="!Exists('$(OutputPath)')" />
    <Csc Sources="@(ServerCompile)" References="$(OutputPath)$(CommonAssemblyName)" OutputAssembly="$(OutputPath)$(ServerAssemblyName)"/>
  </Target>

  <!-- Client -->
  <Target Name="Client" DependsOnTargets="Common" Inputs="@(ClientCompile)" Outputs="$(OutputPath)$(ClientAssemblyName)">
    <MakeDir Directories="$(OutputPath)" Condition="!Exists('$(OutputPath)')" />
    <Csc Sources="@(ClientCompile)" References="$(OutputPath)$(CommonAssemblyName)" OutputAssembly="$(OutputPath)$(ClientAssemblyName)"/>
  </Target>

  <!-- Common -->
  <Target Name="Common" Inputs="@(CommonCompile)" Outputs="$(OutputPath)$(CommonAssemblyName)">
    <MakeDir Directories="$(OutputPath)" Condition="!Exists('$(OutputPath)')" />
    <Csc Sources="@(CommonCompile)" OutputAssembly="$(OutputPath)$(CommonAssemblyName)" TargetType="Library"/>
  </Target>

  <Target Name="Clean">
    <Delete Files="$(OutputPath)$(ServerAssemblyName)" />
    <Delete Files="$(OutputPath)$(ClientAssemblyName)" />
    <Delete Files="$(OutputPath)$(CommonAssemblyName)" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="All" DependsOnTargets="Server;Client;Common" />

  <Target Name="Rebuild" DependsOnTargets="Clean;All" />
</Project>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you doing a `nuget restore` to download the packages?

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey I'm not using an IDE, only VSCode.

Comment: @RonBeyer I tried doing ``msbuild /t:restore``, but I get the error ``the target "restore" does not exist``.

Comment: What version of msbuild are you using?

Comment: Visual Studio community edition is free.  VS Code is great for dealing with front end code.  Not so great with csproj files.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey If I wanted to use an IDE, I'd use an IDE. I want to use MSBuild through the terminal.

Comment: @RonBeyer I'm using version `` 15.5.180.51428``.

Comment: It's fine to learn how to do these things.  My point is that you don't have to rely on other people to answer questions that you can answer yourself by simply going through the exercise with the right tools.

Comment: You may also need a [Nuget.config file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file) and then specify it with the command line: `msbuild /t:restore /p:RestoreConfigFile=<path>`

Comment: @RonBeyer I get the same error ``the target restore does not exist``

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey I have a working csproj generated by VS for this project. But it looks absolutely different from the one I created from scratch (the one I posted above). Also, VS is based on the packages.config, but I read that the "new" way to do it is to use PackageReference on the .csproj instead, so that's what I'm trying to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the old style of csproj:

```xml
<Project DefaultTargets = "All" 
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
```

I don't think `<PackageReference>` is valid there. You want a new, .NET-Core-style project file, which you can tell from the start of it:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
```

You can build that with either the .NET Core SDK (`dotnet build` etc) or MSBuild, although I *think* you'll need the .NET Core SDK installed for it to work even with MSBuild. (Personally I'd suggest using `dotnet build` etc instead of invoking MSBuild, but that's up to you. Either way, you definitely don't need an IDE.)

Adding NuGet dependencies in old-style project files is much more fiddly, as it basically involves adding references to the individual DLLs, along with extra files to make the DLLs available. I'd definitely advise using the new-style project file instead.

Comment: Oh, I see. I followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-pt/visualstudio/msbuild/walkthrough-creating-an-msbuild-project-file-from-scratch) tutorial when creating my .csproj, had no idea there was a new way of doing it. I followed your advice and moved to the new way, and my project now builds successfully. However, it builds everything into a single ``myproj.dll`` file. I need to build one ``server.exe``, one ``client.exe`` and one ``common.dll``. How could I add the build targets I had in my original .csproj file to this new one?

Comment: @Tirafesi: It won't be building everything into a single DLL if you have three projects - which is what it sounds like you should have. If you've got three code-bases, the natural way to organize that is into three projects. Why would you try building it as a single project file?

Comment: You know, you're absolutely right! I thought about making a single project file so I could compile everything at the same time, but I guess that's just not how things are supposed to be done :/ thanks a lot!

Comment: @Tirafesi: You can easily compile everything at the same time if you want to - just create a solution file. Add all the projects to the solution, and build the solution. (This is where at least having some experience with Visual Studio would help you, in terms of understanding what a lot of the project system design reflects. It doesn't mean you need to keep using it, but getting some experience with it would be beneficial.)